# Django - QuerySet filter - combing 2 conditions

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a model(**Delivery**) with 2 fields called **name and to_date**. I just need to a  object with the specific name and it's maximum to_date.

```
Delivery.objects.filter(name__exact = 'name1').aggregate(Max('valid_to'))
```

The above query will return the maximum date. Is it possible to fetch the complete object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a single object ordered by valid_to:

```
obj = Delivery.objects.filter(name='name1', to_date=my_date).order_by('-valid_to')[0]
```

Comment: I thought it was an error as valid_to was not mentioned as a field. Could you post the model as well? Updated code to reflect what I think you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
maximum_to_date = Delivery.objects.filter(name__exact='name1').aggregate(maximum to_date=Max('valid_to'))
result = Delivery.objects.filter(valid_to=maximum_to_date)
```

Note that you need filter() in the second line, because two or more Deliveries might have the same `valid_to` value. In such case you can either accept them all, or e.g. take the one with the smallest ID, depending on what you need.